# How to recover corrupted innodb table from .ibd file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

I forgot to dump the databases before upgrading mysql from 5.5 to 5.7. After upgrade, I ran mysql_upgrade, which ended with the error:

```
Error occurred: Error during call to mysql_check.
```

It seems one of the innodb databases(compressed Barracuda format, over 10GB) is corrupted. I dropped that database, created a new database/table, then dropped the tablespace, copied the original .ibd file to the database directory, and imported the tablespace again:

```
1- create an empty database
2- create a table the same as corrupted one
3- use "ALTER TABLE mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE"
4- copy the original .ibd file in the data folder
5- use "ALTER TABLE mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE"
```

But the `ALTER TABLE mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE` command produces the following error:

```
mysql> alter table mytable import tablespace;
ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'mytable'; try to repair it
```

The mysql log shows this error:

```
 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page offset doesn't match file offset: page offset: 526288, file offset: 526288
[Note] InnoDB: Discarding tablespace of table `mydatabase`.`mytable`: Data structure corruption
```

I'm curious about the error because the page offset obviously matches the file offset.

Note that there is enough disk space for /tmp.

How can I do now?